# Android Dev: What type of tool is this?

Tags: android, mobile, adk

I've been searching for the past couple of hours.  But I'm at a total loss as to what I should be searching for because I don't know what it's called.

I want to have a list of items  Clicking on an item will bring up the "Edit Activity" for that item.  But to the right of each item, should be a clickable red button to DELETE that item.  I've seen this in other apps even in Android notifications.

Is this a standard tool/widget?  Or do I need to create this myself?

If it's a standard tool, what's it called?

Answer (score 1):

the basic idea is to:

1. create or implement ListViewActivity that has the following control for each item: TextView, Button (for edit & delete)
2. create another EditActivity that is launched whenever user click on edit Button

Here's some resources for #1:

1. http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-example
2. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html
3. http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

And here's resources for #2:

1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
2. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html
3. http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html